# How to convert toolbar to side nav bar on window resize (reduce)?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

[Refer this example](http://www.dzurico.com/angular-flex-layout/)

When the browser is full screen, it should display toolbar and its content. But if the browser's width is reduced then new side nav bar should be displayed.
How to achieve this functionality? How to use media queries for this?

Full Screen

[image: Fullscreen]

Reduced width

[image: Reduced width]

I want to use Angular material design for displaying toolbar and side nav bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag with `ngIf` to show and hide sidenav button and toolbar content. Then use `window:resize` event to toggle the flag.

Here's an example for sidenav at screen size < 720px, and other way for >= 720px.

HTML:

```
<md-toolbar [color]="toolbarColor">
    <button *ngIf="openSidenavFlag" md-button color="primary" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </button>￼
    <h1>Angular</h1>
    <div *ngIf="!openSidenavFlag" style="margin: 0 auto">
      <button md-button>Blog</button>
      <button md-button>About</button>
      <button md-button>Contact</button>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<div fxFlex class="app-content">
  This is the content
</div>

<md-sidenav-container (window:resize)="onResize($event)" style="height: 91vh;background: #FFFFFF">

  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" style="background: orange">
    Sidenav!
  </md-sidenav>

</md-sidenav-container>

<footer style="background: skyblue">This is footer</footer>
```

ts:

```
  openSidenavFlag = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.onResize();
  }

  onResize(event) {
    let width;

    if(event != undefined){
      width = event.target.innerWidth;
      // console.log(event.target.innerWidth);
    }
    else{
      // console.log(document.body.clientWidth);
      width = document.body.clientWidth;
    }

    if (width >= 720) {
      this.openSidenavFlag = false;
    } 
    else {
      this.openSidenavFlag = true;
    }

  }
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QWPeqyj6ikSZOMuPM8Lq?p=preview)